# How to merge specific columns with its next column without hardcoding in R programming

Tags: r, tabulizer, pdftools

How to merge column names that are "X" with its next column without hardcode in R programming

X should be merged to Day.7
X.1 should be merged into Day.8
X.2 and X.3 should be merged into Day.9

**Code**:

```
library(data.table)
library(tabulizer)
pdf_file <- "new.pdf"

out2 <- extract_tables(pdf_file, pages =c(89), output = "data.frame")
out2<-as.data.table(out2)

colnames=colnames(out2)
```

**output**:

```
"G" "X"     "Day.7" "X.1"   "Day.8" "X.2"   "Day.9" "X.3"
```

**Expected Output**:

```
"G" "Day.7"     "Day.7" "Day.8"   "Day.8" "Day.9"   "Day.9" "Day.9"
```

PDF DATA is added here:

[image: PDF DATA is added here]

Comment: It is not advised to have duplicate column names? Maybe number them with `Day.7_1` and `Day.7_2` etc. Can you provide data using `dput` i.e edit your post with `dput(head(out2))`.

Comment: @RonakShah, no problem to have duplicate columns, i just want to merge it anyway. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to merge then or just rename them?

Comment: I want to merge

Comment: Please share your data and show expected output for it.

Comment: sorry since the data is confidential, any other way to solve this issue.

Comment: Create a fake dataset which is similar to the data that you have. Show what you have and then show what you want.

Comment: sure.  I will do that and post it here

Comment: how to add my pdf?

Comment: Data is added in the Post

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).